# How to DRY use a Vue.js component with multiple props and slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

In a vuejs application there are 3 components - **TopClicks**.vue, **TopImpressions**.vue, **TopCtr**.vue. Each one of these is using [vue-good-table](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table) *(the component itself is not important, it can be any)* to render almost the same table, but sorted differently:

```
../components/TopClicked.vue (almost 200 lines)

<template>
  <div class="top-clicked">
    <vue-good-table
      mode="remote"
      @on-page-change="onPageChange"
      @on-sort-change="onSortChange"
      :sort-options="{
        enabled: true,
        initialSortBy: {field: 'clicks', type: 'desc'}
      }"
      ... 
    >
      <template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">
        <template v-if="props.column.field === 'keyword'">
          ...
        </template>
        <template v-else-if="props.column.field === 'clicks'">
          ...
        </template>
        <template v-else-if="props.column.field === 'impressions'">
          ...
        </template>
         ...
      </template>
      <template slot="loadingContent">
        <span class="vgt-loading__content">
          ...
        </span>
      </template>
      <template slot="emptystate">
          ...
      </template>
    </vue-good-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table';

export default {
  name: 'TopClicked',
  components: { VueGoodTable},
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          label: this.$t('keyword'),
          field: 'keyword',
        },
        {
          label: this.$t('clicks'),
          field: 'clicks',
        },
        ... more columns
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The other two components - **TopImpressions**.vue and **TopCtr**.vue are almost the same, but with different `:sort-options` param.

My question is: **How to organise my code to avoid making the same change multiple times in the passed to `vue-good-table`' component props or slot templates? How should a component look like, which passes default props and slots to another component, but these can be overwritten when needed?**

It would be great if instead of copying the 200 lines of code from above, a child component *(with base pros and slot templates)* can be created and used like this

```
<vue-good-table-child
  // this should overwrite default :sort-options in vue-good-table-child
  :sort-options="{
    enabled: true,
    initialSortBy: {field: 'impressions', type: 'desc'}
  }"
>
  // this should overwrite default named slot "loadingContent" in vue-good-table-child
  <template slot="loadingContent">
    ...
  </template>
</vue-good-table-child>
```

This way all common code will be in a base component, and only the different props *(or slot templates)* should be passed to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try merging the 3 nearly identical components into 1 component that receives the custom `sortOptions` it needs as a `prop`:

```
// This is the merged component, TopThings.vue, it replaces the instances 
// of TopClicks.vue, TopImpressions.vue, and TopCtr.vue in the parent component

<template>
<div class="top-clicked">
    <vue-good-table
        ...
        :sort-options="sortOptions"
        ...
    />
    ...
</template>

<script>
    ...
    props: {
        sortOptions: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    ...
</script>
```

In your parent component, import the TopThings component and call it in place of each of your 3 previous components, where each implementation is passed its respective `sortOptions`:

```
// This is the parent component where the 3 tables are implemented as 
// separate instances of <TopThings />

<template>
    ...
    <TopThings // this is the TopClicks implementation
        :sort-options="sortOptions.topClicks"
    />
    ...
    <TopThings // this is the TopImpressions implementation
        :sort-options="sortOptions.topImpressions"
    />
    ...
    <TopThings // this is the TopCTR implementation
        :sort-options="sortOptions.topCTR"
    />
    ...
</template>

<script>

components: {
    TopThings.vue,
},
data() {
    return {
        sortOptions: {
            topClicks: {
                enabled: true,
                initialSortBy: {field: 'clicks', type: 'desc'}
            },
            topImpressions: {
                ...
            },
            topCTR: {
                ...
            },
        },
    };
},
```

Comment: You understood the problem right. Thank you for your solution,  but i do not mind passing the parameters that are different as a `component` prop like this `:sort-options="{ enabled: true, initialSortBy: {field: 'clicks', type: 'desc'}}"`. Also I have to mention that the components are on the same page/route.